# jquery function and laravel view

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-4

I want to get a selected item from a dropdown and with jquery redirect to controller function which returns some data to be displayed depending on the selected item. I need some help please.
My controller function is:

```
public function edit($idam)
{
  $records=  table1::join('table2','table2.id','=','table1.id')
  ->where('table2.id','=',$idam+1)
  ->select('table1.id','table2.x')
  ->get();
  return  Response::json($records->toArray();
}
```

in my view: 
<

```
div class="form-group" >
      {{ Form::label('A', 'A') }}
        <div class="right">{{ Form::select('Select_idam',$_adaptivemethods,null,array('id' => 'dbType')) }}</div>
      </div>
```

here where I want to display the datat returned by the javascript function:

```
 <div id= "rData" ></div>
```

and My javascript function is:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){
       $('#dbType').change(function(){    
    $.getJSON("URL::route('home.edit',array($(this).val())) ",function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, terms) {
                    items += terms.id +'terms.x' ;
                });
               $('#rData').html(items);
              $('#rData').show();
            })  
     })
    });
      </script>
```

Comment: Some help in what? What's happening/not happening?

Comment: I don't get the output of the controller function after selecting an item!

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON("URL::route('home.edit',array($(this).val())) ", function (data) {`

URL::route won't work as it is a Laravel (PHP) function. Try hardcoding in the URL and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: I changed this to   $.getJSON('/laravel/public/home/edit'+$(this).val() ,function (data) {

Comment: the required output isn't displayed :(

Comment: Try using a full URL and console.log to see what is displayed. Also making use of Firefox to see what the server is returning might give you better insights of what is going wrong.